# Why does std::async copy its const & arguments?

Tags: c++, gcc, asynchronous, c++11, std

I'm trying to speed up a program by using std::async. Let's say I have a function

```
T* f (const T& t1, const T& t2, const T& t3)
```

Where T is a type that is expensive to copy.  I have several independent calls of f with different arguments and I try to parallelize them with std::async approximately like this: (where m_futures is a std::vector of futures of the correct type).

```
for (...) {
   m_futures.push_back (
       std::async(
           std::launch::async,
           f,
           a,b,c));
}
```

I observed that the above code slows down the execution of my program. I stepped through it with gdb and when the future is created, the copy constructor of T is called three times.  Why is that? The arguments a,b,c are heap allocated, but maybe the compiler does not know about it?  Can I make it explicit somehow?

Is it always the case that std::async creates copies of the arguments, even if they should be passed by const reference? Can I avoid this somehow?  In my naive mind, there should just be a pointer passed around to the different invocations of the function (which only reads from the memory anyway.)  I'm using gcc-4.6.3 on Linux if that matters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It wouldn't be safe to store references only, since there's nothing to guarantee the absence of data races (and more profoundly, the mere *existence* of objects, as @utapistim said in her sadly deleted post).

If you actually want a reference rather than a copy, and *you*'re willing to bet your life on this being correct, then you can simply use a reference wrapper:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, f, std::cref(a), std::cref(b), std::cref(c))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if I change the interface and explicitly pass a pointer?  Would that be equivalent to using reference wrappers?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes. Reference wrappers *are* essentially pointers. Don't use naked pointers in C++ (except as private class members). Prefer the reference wrappers.

Comment: OK, Thanks, I did not know about reference wrapping.

Comment: @Thomas: I think the reference wrappers were essentially *invented* for the purpose of calling `thread` constructors and `async` and such like.

Comment: @KerrekSB Well, originally probably rather for `std::bind` and friends in the first place, and to accomodate for the (pre-11) lack of perfect forwarding for automatic deduction of reference arguments.

Comment: @ChristianRau, you're right it was invented for `std::bind` but I don't see what perfect forwarding has to do with it, being able to distinguish between lvalues and rvalues doesn't help a call wrapper know whether it should forward an argument by value or by reference, only the caller can know which is appropriate for a given call.

Comment: @JonathanWakely While thinking about a counter-argument/example I realize you are right. Whereas perfect forwarding can help  with forwarding lvalues as references it is actually the caller's responsibility if he wants to pass the lvalue as reference or not. So just ignore the second part of my previous comment.

Comment: @KerrekSB *It wouldn't be safe to store references only, since there's nothing to guarantee the absence of data races*. How to understand that in the right way?It seems that there still may be data races even if you calls the `std::ref()`.