# Can compiler optimize return value from copy to a reference?

Tags: c++, optimization, concurrency

If I write the code this way:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> Bar::getFoo()
{
    return m_foo;
}

void somewhereElse()
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo = myBar.getFoo();
    //do some stuff with foo
}
```

Can compiler somehow optimize the code so it will be changed to something like that:

```
void somewhereElse()
{
    const shared_ptr<Foo> &foo = myBar.getFoo__by_ref_somehow();
    //do some stuff with foo
}
```

I'm asking because it could be a problem in case of concurrent execution.

I understand that RVO can be applied and remove an extra copy, but could compiler eliminate the copy at all?

Comment: I think that it would even be a mistake, if compiler would do that. Because by creating a copy you do create two different instances which you can edit separately. What would be something somebody else could rely on while writing the same code as you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You asked for a value, so you *get* a value. Copy elision is about eliding unnecessary copies. You wanted a value; the function returns a value. So you're going to get at least one copy. What you're wanting is some form of code transformation, turning a value into a reference.

You could *create* a function `getFoo__by_ref_somehow`, which returns a `const&` to the value stored in the class. But that would be a different function that you *create*, not something a compiler is allowed to create for you.

Comment: If you ask for a reference, you can get a value, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851163/why-does-stdasync-copy-its-const-arguments

Comment: @Thomas: No, that's copying into a value from a reference. The function itself returned a reference.