# pending std::future get of std::async with shared_from_this argument blocks destruction of this

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++17

I wanted to create a class that would represent a task that can be started running asynchronously and will run continuously (effectively in a detached thread) until a stop signal is received. The usage for the sake of this question would look like this:

```
auto task = std::make_shared<Task>();
task->start(); // starts the task running asynchronously
... after some time passes ...
task->stop(); // signals to stop the task
task->future.get(); // waits for task to stop running and return its result
```

However, a key feature of this `Task` class is that I cannot guarantee that the future will be waited/got... i.e. the last line may not get called before the shared pointer is destroyed.

A stripped-down toy version of the class I wrote is as follows (please ignore that everything is in public, this is just for this example's simplicity):

```cpp
class MyClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass> {
public:
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl; }

    void start() {
        future = std::async(std::launch::async, &MyClass::method, this->shared_from_this());
    }
    void stop() { m_stop = true; }

    void method() {
        std::cout << "running" << std::endl;
        do {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        } while(m_stop == false);
        std::cout << "stopped" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::future<void> future;
    std::atomic<bool> m_stop = false;

};
```

However, I discovered an undesirable feature of this code: if instead of `get` on the future, I just `wait` (e.g. if I don't care about the result of `method`, which in this case is a void anyway), then when `task` is deleted, the instance doesn't get destroyed.

I.e. doing `task->future.get()` gives:

```
running
stopped
Destructor called
```

But `task->future.wait()` gives:

```
running
stopped
```

From reading answer to [What is the lifetime of the arguments of std::async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505280/what-is-the-lifetime-of-the-arguments-of-stdasync) I believe the problem here is the `this->shared_from_this()` argument to `std::async` won't be destroyed until the future from the async has been made invalid (through `get` or destruction or otherwise). So this shared_ptr is keeping the class instance alive.

---

*Solution Attempt 1:*

Replace the line in `start` with:

```cpp
future  = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() {
            return this->shared_from_this()->method();
        });
```

This ensures shared_ptr it creates is destroyed when the method completes, but I have been worried that there's nothing to stop `this` being destroyed between the time of it being captured by the lambda capture (which happens at this line, correct?) and the time the lambda is executed in the new thread. Is this a real possibility?

---

*Solution Attempt 2:*

To protect the `this` (`task`) being destroyed before the lambda function runs, I add another member variable `std::shared_ptr<MyClass> myself` then my start method can look like this:

```cpp
myself = this->shared_from_this();
future  = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]() {
            auto my_ptr = std::move(this->myself);
            return myself->method();
});
```

Here the idea is that `myself` will ensure that if I delete the `task` shared_ptr, I don't destroy the class. Then inside the lambda, the shared_ptr is transferred to the local `my_ptr` variable, which is destroyed on exit.

---

Are there issues with this solution, or have I overlooked a much cleaner way of achieving the sort functionality I'm after?

Thanks!

Comment: Re attempt 1: _"but I have been worried that there's nothing to stop this being destroyed"_ - can you just add a destructor that waits on the future?

Comment: A good suggestion, but when I tried this, the async thread would hang at the `shared_from_this` call. In addition, if I wanted to use this logic as part of a base class, where the main async work is done in a virtual method, having the wait in the base destructor will be too late - I would have ensure all derived methods call the wait in their destructors

Comment: I think that problem might vanish if you use composition instead of inheritance

Comment: Why are you using `this->shared_from_this()` in the async call instead of `this` in the first place? You will not run into a lifetime problem of the object, because you call `get` or `wait` before destruction

Comment: @MikevanDyke - I wanted the behaviour to be that I couldn't guarantee that get/wait would be called ... I'll clarify this point in the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution attempt 2 I found in some scenarios would generate a deadlock exception. This appears to come from the async thread simultaneously trying to destroy the future (by destroying the instance of the class) while also trying to set the value of the future.

---

*Solution attempt 3* - this seems to pass all my tests so far:

```
myself = this->shared_from_this();
std::promise<void> p;
future = p.get_future();
std::thread([this](std::promise<void>&& p) {
            p.set_value_at_thread_exit( myself->method() );
            myself.reset();
}, std::move(p)).detach();
```

The logic here is that it is safe to destroy `myself` (by resetting the shared pointer) once the method call is finished - its safe to delete the future of a promise before the promise has set its value. No deadlock occurs because the future is destroyed before the promise tries to transfer a value.

Any comments on this solution or potentially neater alternatives would be welcome. In particular it would be good to know if there are issues I've overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of the following solutions:

Solution 1, Use `std::async` with `this` instead of `shared_from_this`:

```
class MyClass /*: public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass> not needed here */ {
public:
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << "Destructor called" << std::endl; }

    void start() {
        future = std::async(std::launch::async, &MyClass::method, this);
    }
    void stop() { m_stop = true; }

    void method() {
        std::cout << "running" << std::endl;
        do {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        } while(m_stop == false);
        std::cout << "stopped" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::atomic<bool> m_stop = false;
    std::future<void> future; // IMPORTANT: future constructed last, destroyed first
};
```

This solution would work even if not calling `wait` or `get` on the future because the [destructor of a future returned by `std::async` blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23455104/7699037) until the termination of the task. It is important to construct the future last, so that it is destroyed (and thus blocks) before all other members are destroyed. If this is too risky, use solution 3 instead.

---

Solution 2, Use a detached thread like you did:

```
 void start() {
    std::promise<void> p;
    future = p.get_future();
    std::thread(
        [m = this->shared_from_this()](std::promise<void>&& p) {
          m->method();
          p.set_value();
        },
        std::move(p))
        .detach();
  }
```

One drawback of this solution: If you have many instances of `MyClass` you will create a lot of threads maybe resulting in contention. So a better option would be to use a thread pool instead of a single thread per object.

---

Solution 3, Separate the executable from the task class e.g:

```
class ExeClass {
 public:
  ~ExeClass() { std::cout << "Destructor of ExeClass" << std::endl; }
  void method() {
    std::cout << "running" << std::endl;
    do {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    } while (m_stop == false);
    std::cout << "stopped" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  std::atomic<bool> m_stop = false;
};

class MyClass {
 public:
  ~MyClass() { std::cout << "Destructor of MyClass" << std::endl; }

  void start() {
    future = std::async(std::launch::async, &ExeClass::method, exe);
  }
  void stop() { exe->m_stop = true; }

  std::shared_ptr<ExeClass> exe = std::make_shared<ExeClass>();
  std::future<void> future;
};
```

Like solution 1 this would block when the future is destroyed, however you don't need to take care of the order of construction and destruction. IMO this is the cleanest option.