# Is it safe to pass stack variables by reference to multithreaded code?

Tags: c++, multithreading

As an example in pseudocode:

```
MultiThreadedWorker worker;

Foo()
{
    const Vector position = CreatePosition();
    
    worker.StartWorker(Position);
}

MultiThreadedWorker::StartWorker(const Vector& myPosition)
{
    ... Do a bunch of async work that keeps referencing myPosition ...
}
```

This seems to be working for now, but I don't understand why because it seems that myPosition would end up pointing to nothing long before StartWorker completed.

Assuming this isn't safe, is there any solution other than just passing around everything by value or ensuring it's all on the heap?

Comment: It all depends on the life-time of the variables compared to the threads.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] instead of the pseudo code?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's what I was afraid of, but isn't that just creating a race condition? For instance it seemed that a meet in the middle type solution was for the thread to create a local copy, but even then if it's the first thing it does, it seems that it's racing against the life-time of the Foo function.

Comment: @RussellBearden Standard library functions which create threads, such as the `std::thread` constructor and `std::async` do exactly that. They construct a copy of the arguments in the context of the caller but on the stack of the thread. The thread function is then passed references to these copies. That way there is no data race. Your question doesn't specify how you are creating threads, so it is difficult to answer. If you create threads manually using the OS API (which I am not sure why you would do that) things might be different.

Comment: Will the `Foo` function use `position` after it started the thread, or are there multiple threads working on the same data? If not, then why not *move* it into the thread.

Comment: @user17732522 That makes perfect sense. And the answer proposed by SargeATM further clarified.

Comment: If you are not sure about the lifetime, consider creating a std::shared_ptr to your data and then starting a lambda with that shared_ptr captured by value. e.g. `auto position_ptr = std::make_shared<Vector>; auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [position_ptr]{ // .. use position_ptr here; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## std::async copies const references

So yes, it is safe. For a discussion of why it does, see [Why does std::async copy its const & arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851163/why-does-stdasync-copy-its-const-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

It is programmers responsibility to ensure that variable live long enough so that it is not destroyed before any access through pointers or references. This can be achieved through at least by one of the following:

1. Ensure the thread ends before destroying the variable. You can run .join() on the thread before leaving the scope.
2. Create object on the heap. Create it using `make_shared` and pass `shared_ptr`. This ensures the object lives until the last reference is destroyed.

Note that there is another problem with threads and shared objects. If one thread writes when another thread reads to the same object, then it is a data race which is Undefined Behavior. Thread synchronization mechanisms such as `std::mutex` can be used to avoid this.